# How to create an index in Postgres on an expression involving TEXT columns and a DATE column, concatenated?

Tags: postgresql, date, indexing

I want to be able to search for people "similar" to what I have in the database (e.g. a person with a typo in their name or date of birth).  I want to use the `levenshtein` function for that in the following way:

```sql
create temp table person (first_name text, last_name text, dob date);
select * from person where levenshtein('johndoe2000-01-01', lower(first_name || last_name || dob)) < 4;
```

(I am aware this can be probably optimized a bit by e.g. using `YYYYMMDD` instead of `YYYY-MM-DD`, but that is irrelevant to my question.)

I thought that I could speed up the search with an index.  However, I don't know how to create one that would work:

```sql
create index fuzzy on person ((lower(first_name || last_name || dob)));
```

results in `ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE`.  I tried a few things: using `concat` instead of `||`, casting `dob` to `text` explicitly or with `to_char`, but to no avail.  What am I doing wrong?  It seems that the problem results from mixing `text` and `date` – I can create an index with only `text` columns or only the `date` column without a problem.

Comment: Dates are binary values, they have no format. Indexes can cover multiple columns, they don't need and *shouldn't* use text concatenation, otherwise you'll end up with out-of-order index entries just because two columns differed by a letter, eg `Ban` and `anana` vs `Bana` and `nana`

Comment: Ok, so what you mean is that my idea is a _bad practice_, and that I understand – but why doesn't it _work_? And I'm not even 100% convinced – if I use some expression in my `where` clause, shouldn't using the exact same expression in the index speed things up?

Comment: No, for two reasons. Indexes work because they're ordered (and in a [B-tree structure](https://blog.quest.com/a-guide-to-using-postgres-indexes/)) which allows quickly finding a match or a range *without* having to scan all results. Just a few nodes in the tree. For that to work, the ordering of the nodes should be valid. Second, calculating the Levenshtein distance requires processing *all* values. The index offers no benefit in this case except buffering - the database buffers indexes in memory much more aggressively than data

Comment: To speed up similarity searches you need something like [pg_trm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/pgtrgm.html) which offers special matching and index operators.

Answer (score 1):

The exercise is pointless: you can never use an index to speed up a query that uses `levenshtein()`.

Answer (score 0):

Casting dates to strings depends on database setting that might change, and so it is not immutable.

```
select '2021-04-03'::date::text;
 2021-04-03
set datestyle TO 'german';
select '2021-04-03'::date::text;
 03.04.2021
```

You could solve that problem in a variety of ways. But once you do, it still wouldn't work as levenshtein distance is generally not indexable.